# JavaScript Regexp Replace?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression which will wrap all occurences of `JJDnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn` within a string with an anchor pointing to an url which contains the matched string in the query string.

I suck at regexps :(

Comment: Literally, "JJDnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn", or do the n's represent numbers?

Comment: sorry yes, i should be more specific the n's represent 0-9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace JJD with exactly 16 digits after it, you could say

```
str.replace(/(JJD[0-9]{16})/gi,"<a href='somepage.html/foo?value=$1'>$1</a>");
```

if you don't need exactly 16 digits, but need something like 10-20 digits, you could say

```
str.replace(/(JJD[0-9]{10,20})/gi,"<a href='somepage.html/foo?value=$1'>$1</a>");
```

Comment: I feel such a fool. Thanks :)